# Can somebody explain the main OOP concept behind Spring Framework.

Tags: spring, oop, polymorphism, abstraction

I had this question on an interview and I answered Abstraction and Polymorphism.  But I was not able to properly justify the answer.
Please Help me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) started out as an [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container. article says: ... "The term is related to, but different from, the dependency inversion principle, ...", so *maybe* they wanted to hear [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). ioc is also called the [hollywood principle](http://wiki.c2.com/?HollywoodPrinciple).